# AngularjS Connection Timeout to ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, connection

I have 2 servers setup, "client" with an angularjs working app, and "server" with elasticsearch running with proper indexing.  I can curl from client to server and return the expected data, however my angular app cannot.  I have iptables turned off, so i'm not sure why its not working.  My angular connection code:

```
  .service('esClient', function (esFactory) {
    esClient = esFactory({
      host: 'server.develop.com:9200',
      apiVersion: '1.4',
      log: 'trace'
    });
    return esClient;
  })
```

The error i see:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
elasticsearch.angular.js:34871 ERROR: 2015-02-08T19:55:39Z
  Error: Request error, retrying -- Connection Failure
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the HTTP protocol prefix. Do

```
host : 'http://server.develop.com:9200'
```

Hope this helps.